# how to change track name and colour in IGV using batch script

Tags: batch-file

Any one know how to change track name and colour using batch script in IGV?

I found an example script in the link: 
http://software.broadinstitute.org/software/igv/automation
The example script does the following:
Loads a file
Sets genome and snapshot directory
Jumps to a specified loci
Sorts, Collapses, and then takes a snapshot of the screen
Repeats these steps for other loci

However, I could not find the information on how to change track name and colour using batch script.
Thanks in advance for any help!